# Calling a method in another class from the controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to asp.net mvc projects. I want to call a method in another class from ActionResult Index() method in Home Controller.

eg:

```
public class RestCall{
  public async Task<ActionResult> RestCall(string a, string b){
    //......
  }
}
```

I want to access RestCall() method from index method in following class and I want to get the output of RestCall class to the index() method in home controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

(I am using razor syntax.)Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: Technically, your question doesn't have an answer. You can't call a method in another class unless that method is static. You can only call the method on an *instance* of that class. Normally, you would do that by calling `var x = new RestClass()` followed by x.RestClass("foo", "bar")`, but since it won't compile if you have a class that has a method with the same name that is not a constructor, that won't work. Please change your example to code that *will compile*.

Answer (score 1):

Change your definition of `Index()` to be async and await `RestCall`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   RestCall rc = new RestCall();
   //rename method as @NightOwl88 says
   var result = await rc.DoRestCall("somestring", "somestring").ConfigureAwait(false); 
   // do something with result
   return View();
}
```